# Data capture from ORM (Optical Mark Recognition) sheet in Java

Tags: java, omr

i need to develop software for capture omr sheet data in java.pl.

Comment: OMR = [Optical Mark Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Mark_Recognition)? [Optical Music Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_music_recognition)?

Comment: optical mark recognition

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking at music recognition for printed music scores, [OpenOMR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openomr/) might provide a solution.

For Optical Mark Recognition have a look at [Udai OMR](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aseth/udai/OMRProj/README.html), it is Java and sources are available.

Comment: @Unknown - a downvote? You're kidding. Or not? please leave a note.

Comment: @Aswan - if the answer is helpful, please accept or upvote or at least leave a comment. Otherwise I delete this answer because I don't like being downvoted for spending time on some internet research.

Comment: can we use udai OMR in android ??

Comment: pls reply if OMR is possible in android